# Qual a diferença entre htmlspecialchars() e htmlentities()?

Tags: php

Certa vez tive que usar htmlentities() para resolver uma determinada situação de codificação (as palavras com acento não estavam com os caracteres) e vi que existia esse htmlspecialchars().

No Php.net, vi as seguintes definições:

> htmlentities -> Converte todos os caracteres aplicáveis em entidades
>   html
>
> htmlspecialchars -> Converte caracteres especiais para a realidade
>   HTML

O que me deu a entender que não existe diferença entre os dois. Mas acredito que posso estar equivocado, até porque o uso de parâmetros de uma função pode diferir da outra.

Eles são a mesma coisa? Se não forem, em que caso um e o outro?

Comment: Relacionado em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Comment: O que seria uma realidade html? uma dimensão só de tags html?

Comment: Tbm não entendi bem a definição :(

Comment: @DiChrist chegou a ler a minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252675/3635)?

Comment: Li agora pouco. Neste caso ela atende a minha pergunta de maneira mais satisfatória.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não são somente com o `<`, `>` e `&`, `htmlentities` é bem mais do que isso

### htmlspecialchars

> Descrição
>
> ```
> string htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
> ```

Irá converter caracteres para entidades que afetam o HTML, sendo as conversões as seguintes:

- `&` irá se tornar `&amp;`
- `>` irá se tornar `&lt;`
- `<` irá se tornar `&gt;`
- `"` irá se tornar `&quot;` (exceto quando `ENT_NOQUOTES` está definido nas `$flags`)
- `'` irá se tornar `&amp;`, converte para `&#039;` quando `$flags` tiver `ENT_HTML401` ou `&apos;` quando for `ENT_XML1`, `ENT_XHTML` ou `ENT_HTML5`, mas somente quando definido as `$flags` com `ENT_QUOTES`

### htmlentities

> Descrição
>
> ```
> string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
> ```

O comportamento é idêntico ao `htmlspecialchars` por padrão para `&`, `>`, `<`, `"` e `'` especificamente, ou seja em nada muda ([**por este motivo discordo da outra resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108896/3635)), o que `htmlentities` difere é que além dos caracteres citados, ele irá converter todos caracteres que tem representação em entidades HTML, segue listas dos caracteres:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html
- https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Um exemplo simples de diferença são os acentos:

```
<?php

echo htmlspecialchars('<foo><bar>Olá Mundo!</bar></foo>'), "\n";

echo htmlentities('<foo><bar>Olá Mundo!</bar></foo>'), "\n";
```

O resultado será este:

> ```
>  &lt;foo&gt;&lt;bar&gt;Olá Mundo!&lt;/bar&gt;&lt;/foo&gt;
>  &lt;foo&gt;&lt;bar&gt;Ol&aacute; Mundo!&lt;/bar&gt;&lt;/foo&gt;
> ```

Exemplo no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/AldiIB)

Note também que o comportamento de ambas funções podem ser ajustados pelas flags:

- `ENT_COMPAT`, `ENT_QUOTES`, `ENT_NOQUOTES`, `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`, `ENT_DISALLOWED`, `ENT_HTML401`, `ENT_XML1`, `ENT_XHTML` e `ENT_HTML5`

Ou seja isto reforça que o que difere em ambas função não são os caracteres `< > &` citados na outra resposta:

> Eles fazem a mesma coisa com exceção de alguns caracteres " < > & "

### Comportamentos

Outros comportamentos podem variar conforme as tais `$flags` que eu já citei, e também pode mudar com o uso do `$encoding` e `$double_encode`, no entanto isso são configurações especificas conforme a necessidade.

Answer (score 5):

Eles fazem a mesma coisa com exceção de alguns caracteres " < > & "

CASO 1:

```
$html = "onclick='location:/?page=1&cat=3'"

echo htmlspecialchars($html);

result: onclick='location:/?page=1&cat=3'
```

CASO 2

```
$html = "onclick='location:/?page=1&cat=3'"

echo htmlentities($html);

result: onclick='location:/?page=1&#38;cat=3'
```