# Exibir código na página

Tags: php, html5

Que tag uso para exibir um código qualquer na página? Ou seja, como faço para exibir códigos de **PHP** ou qualquer outro na página de forma que o navegador o leia como texto e não interprete como código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que usar `&lt;` e `&gt;` (HTML Entities), algo como:

```html
<pre>
&lt;?php
    
echo 'Olá';
<pre>
```

Você pode tornar isto mais fácil usando a função `htmlspecialchars` do proprio PHP, por exemplo, supondo que vá ler um script e exibi-lo:

```
<pre>
<?php
$dados = file_get_contents('script.php');
echo htmlspecialchars($dados);
?>
</pre>
```

> Aproveite e leia sobre algumas diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre htmlspecialchars() e htmlentities()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252675/3635)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi 100% mas parece que você está buscando algo como a função highlight_file.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.highlight-file.php

Exemplo de uso: highlight_file('myFile.php');